# Acer (Maple) white spots and dieback - infection and how to treat

Tags: fungus, maple

For some time now my Acer has been dying back and appears to be infected - see the white spots on the trunk and the bark dieback. Is this something which can be treated - and if so how?

The photos I think summarise the issue well so I'm just looking to understand precisely what the condition is.

[image: Acer dieback]
[image: Acer trunk white spots]

Comment: I see the white but does the tree also bleed sap? I can sort of see it but need confirmation

Comment: I don't think the white spots are the cause.

Answer (score 1):

The white spots are Lichen and are harmless.  Looks like an animal has been dining on the bark.  My guess is rabbit.

Comment: I doubt it - in an urban (sealed) garden with no pet rabbits known nearby. Plus, the dieback extends to the top of the plant which a rabbit or similar would be unable to reach (this example is c. 1 m tall).